# WP categories blog post pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, posts, timber

I'm trying to paginate my categories blog posts. I'm using timber.

in my category.php i'm doing this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'page' => $paged,
'category' => get_query_var('cat')
);

$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
```

but if i go to */page/2 i get the same posts of */page/1

i can't understand what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: I think the problem is with your expected URL structure. For queries is *?paged=2 not */page/2

Comment: If i go to ?paged=2 i got this redirect /page/2?paged=2 and a 404 error